# Using Stanford tools to parse French with Universal Dependencies

Tags: parsing, french

I want to parse French text with Universal Dependencies using Stanford Parser version 3.7.0 (the last one).

Here is my command :

```
"java -mx2100m -cp stanford-parser.jar:stanford-french-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -MAX_ITEMS 5000000 -encoding utf-8 -outputFormat conll2007 -outputFormatOptions includePunctuationDependencies -sentences newline frenchFactored.ser.gz "+startinDir+"/"+fic+" > "+startinDir+"/Parses_FR/"+fic_name
```

I use the last models available https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml#Download

But my output doesn't contain any function, and the POS are not the ones of UD

> 1 La  _   D   D   _   2   NULL    _   _
>
> 2 pluie   _   N   N   _   3   NULL    _   _
>
> 3 bat _   V   V   _   0   root    _   _
>
> 4 les _   D   D   _   5   NULL    _   _
>
> 5 carreaux    _   N   N   _   3   NULL    _   _

I am also trying to use the parser tool of the CoreNLP, here is my commandline :

```
java -mx1g -cp stanford-corenlp-3.7.0.jar:stanford-french-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse -file /Users/Rafael/Desktop/LANGAGES/CORPUS/Sentences_FR/3aube_schtrouFR30.txt -outputFormat sortie.txt
```

My properties files contains these lines :

> annotators = tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse
>
> tokenize.language = fr
>
> parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/frenchFactored.ser.gz
>
> pos.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/french/french.tagger
>
> depparse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_French.gz
> depparse.language = french

I get the following error message

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/french/french.tagger" as class path, filename or URL

How can I fix that?